# How can I customize the plain side header with the renewcommand if parameters cause in an error

Tags: header-footer, koma-script, fancyhdr

Minimal working example:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, oneside, parskip=half]{scrbook}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead{}
\fancyfoot{}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\MakeUppercase{\thechapter.\ #1}}{}}
\lhead[\leftmark]{\MakeUppercase{\leftmark}}
\rhead[\pagemark]{\pagemark}

\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
    %\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\MakeUppercase{#1}}{}} %error
    %\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\MakeUppercase{##1}}{}} %nothing happend
    \fancyhead{}%
    \fancyfoot{}%
    \rhead[\pagemark]{\pagemark}%
}

\begin{document}
    \chapter{This is a minimal working example}
    \blindtext[8]
\end{document}
```

I want to show the chapter title without the leading number. Both commented `\renewcommand`s did not work.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! I'm not sure to understand what you want to achieve. Can you explain better?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is another suggestion using `scrlayer-scrpage` and defining a new `mark`:

```
\documentclass[12pt, oneside, parskip=half]{scrbook}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage[manualmark,markcase=upper,headsepline,plainheadsepline]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\clearpairofpagestyles
\setkomafont{pagehead}{\upshape}
\ohead*{\pagemark}

\newmarks\chaptermarkwithoutnum
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\chaptermark[1]{%
  % code by @Schweinebacke (see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/452733/9057):
  \begingroup
    \let\label\relax \let\index\relax \let\glossary\relax
    \@temptokena{#1}%
    \unrestored@protected@xdef\@themark{\the\@temptokena}%
    \@temptokena\expandafter\expandafter{\expandafter\MakeMarkcase\expandafter{\@themark}}%
    \marks\chaptermarkwithoutnum{\the\@temptokena}%
  \endgroup
  %
  \markboth{\MakeMarkcase{\ifnumbered{chapter}{\chaptermarkformat}{}#1}}{}%
}
\makeatother
\ihead[\firstmarks\chaptermarkwithoutnum]{\leftmark}

\begin{document}
\chapter{This is a minimal working example}
\Blindtext[10]
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

**Update**

Suggestion without an additional mark:

```
\documentclass[12pt, oneside, parskip=half]{scrbook}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage[markcase=upper,headsepline,plainheadsepline]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\automark[chapter]{chapter}
\clearpairofpagestyles
\setkomafont{pagehead}{\upshape}
\ohead*{\pagemark}

\renewcommand\chaptermark[1]{%
  \markboth{\MakeMarkcase{\ifnumbered{chapter}{\chaptermarkformat}{}#1}}{\MakeMarkcase{#1}}%
}
\ihead[\righttopmark]{\leftmark}

\begin{document}
\chapter{This is a minimal working example}
\Blindtext[10]
\end{document}
```

The result is the same as above.

Comment: Here you should use a similar definition to that of https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/452733/9057. Otherwise you would get errors if `\MakeMarkcase` is `\MakeUppercase` and also the `\usekomafont`s are not needed (and are dangerous outside the inner mark arguments).

Answer (score 3):

[`fancyhdr`](http://ctan.org/pkg/fancyhdr) should typically not be used with KOMA-script classes, as you'll receive the following warning in your `.log`:

```
Class scrbook Warning: Usage of package `fancyhdr' together
(scrbook)              with a KOMA-Script class is not recommended.
(scrbook)              I'd suggest to use 
(scrbook)              package `scrlayer-scrpage'.
(scrbook)              Nevertheless, using requested
(scrbook)              package `fancyhdr' on input line 3.
```

However, here's how you can obtain the output you're after. That is, the `plain` page style (associated with the first page of a chapter) show the chapter title *without* a number, while other pages show it with a number:

[image]

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}% Clear header/footer
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\MakeUppercase{\thechapter.\ #1}}{}}
\lhead[\leftmark]{\MakeUppercase{\leftmark}}
\rhead[\pagemark]{\pagemark}

\makeatletter
\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
  \fancyhf{}% Clear header/footer
  \rhead[\pagemark]{\pagemark}%
  \lhead{\MakeUppercase{\scr@ds@head}}% Chapter title
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\chapter{This is a minimal working example}
\blindtext[8]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank's for your fast answer Werner. What did you recommend as alternative to fancyhdr.

Comment: @AlexanderCzyrny: Follow the KOMA-script suggestion: [`scrlayer-scrpage`](http://ctan.org/pkg/scrlayer-scrpage).

Answer (score 1):

Redefining `\chaptermark` in the page style is completely useless, because the command is issued by `\chapter`.

I'm not sure what the aim is: I find it wrong having the chapter title at the top of the starting chapter page, as the same title is a few lines below.

However, a trick is to hide the chapter number in a macro that can be locally redefined to return nothing when the plain header is to be typeset.

The `scrbook` class warns you that there are Koma-script methods for setting headers and footers, but allows you to use `fancyhdr` nonetheless. However, I changed the syntax to a better one.

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, oneside, parskip=half]{scrbook}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\newrobustcmd{\perhaps}[1]{#1}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\perhaps{\thechapter.\ }#1}{}}
\fancyhead{}
\fancyfoot{}
\fancyhead[L]{\MakeUppercase{\leftmark}}
\fancyhead[R]{\thepage}

\makeatletter
\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
  \fancyhf{}%
  \fancyhead[L]{\let\perhaps\@gobble\MakeUppercase{\leftmark}}%
  \fancyhead[R]{\thepage}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\chapter{This is a minimal working example}

\blindtext[8]

\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]