# Include chapter, section and subsection in running head

Tags: header-footer, scrlayer-scrpage

I’m using scrlayer-scrpage to get chapter and section in my running head:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage[headsepline,automark,autooneside=false]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\clearpairofpagestyles
\ihead{\leftmark\ifstr{\rightmark}{\leftmark}{}{ --- \rightmark}}

% remove section numbers before section text 
\renewcommand*{\sectionmarkformat}{} 

\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Cht}
\section{Sct}
\lipsum
\subsection{Subsection}
\lipsum
\section{SScctt}
\lipsum
\chapter{Next}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Resulting in:

1 Cht — Sct

Yet, is there a way to include the subsection? So that it looks like this:

1 Cht — Sct — Subsection

And is there a way to check if there is a curren Section/Subsection in the current chapter, since I’ve seen cases that the section refers to the one in a previous chapter...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe the following does what you want:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage[headsepline,autooneside=false]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\automark[subsection]{section}
\renewcommand*{\sectionmarkformat}{}
\renewcommand*{\subsectionmarkformat}{}

\newmarks\chaptermarkwithnum
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\chaptermark[1]{%
  % code changed/added by @Schweinebacke:
  \begingroup
    \let\label\relax \let\index\relax \let\glossary\relax
    \@temptokena{\ifnumbered{chapter}{\chaptermarkformat}{}#1}%
    \unrestored@protected@xdef\@themark{\the\@temptokena}%
    \@temptokena\expandafter\expandafter{\expandafter\MakeMarkcase\expandafter{\@themark}}%
   \marks\chaptermarkwithnum{\the\@temptokena}%
  \endgroup
  %
  \markboth{}{}%
}
\makeatother

\clearpairofpagestyles
\ihead{%
  \firstmarks\chaptermarkwithnum
  \ifstr{\leftbotmark}{}{}{
   --- \leftbotmark\ifstr{\rightbotmark}{\leftbotmark}{}{ --- \rightbotmark}%
  }%
}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Cht}
\section{Sct}
\lipsum
\subsection{Subsection}
\lipsum
\section{SScctt}
\lipsum
\chapter{Next}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

---

The mark mechanism is used for the running header entries. A mark command sets three variables: one for the last mark of the previous page, one for the first mark set on the current page and one for the last mark set on the current page. When a page starts the three variables are equal.

`\markright` sets its argument as the "right" mark. `\markboth` sets its first argument as the "left" mark and its second argument as the "right" mark.

`\rightmark` uses the first "right" mark set by `\markright` or the second argument of `\markboth` on a page. `\leftmark` uses the last (bottom) "left" mark set by the first argument of `\markboth`. The KOMA-Script class provides also `\righttopmark`, `\rightfirstmark`, `\rightbotmark`, `\lefttopmark` etc.

If chapter, section and subsection should be in the running header an three marks are needed.

With `\automark[subsection]{section}` each `\section` command executes `\markboth` with the section in its first and its second argument and each `\subsection` executes `\markright` with the subsection in its argument. So `\leftbotmark` is the last section on the page and `\rightbotmark` is either the last section or the last subsection on the page.

To add the chapter in a third mark an additional mark must be defined. In the example it is `\chaptermarkwithnum`. Then `\chaptermark` is redefined to set this new mark. Therefore an adaption of LaTeX's \markboth definition is used (thanks to @Schweinebacke). Additionally `\markboth{}{}` cleans the "right" and the "left" mark. So in a new chapter `\leftbotmark` and `\rightbotmark` are empty until the next `\section` command.

For the header entry in `\ihead` the first value of the new mark and the last values of the left and the right mark are used.

Comment: Very sophisticated. I don't even understand `\newmarks` and `\marks` and by the way, I've got no idea what you are doing there. If the wonderful weather doesn't distract you: could you include some words of explanation, please?

Comment: I second @KeksDose. Very well done, and it works conditionally! But some explanation would be really cool to understand the code better! Thank you!!

Comment: @esdd I just noticed that the answer you provided sets the entire body text in italic... cannot figure out why that is...

Comment: @esdd I deleted the line `\usekomafont{pageheadfoot}\usekomafont{pagehead}%` This doesn’t touch the body text. Can you update your answer accordingly?

Comment: @esdd I've adapted your definition of `\chaptermark`. Now, it even works if `\MakeMarkcase` is, e.g., `\MakeUppercase`. The `\usekomafont`s are not needed because they are automatically part of the head definition not the marks.

Comment: @Schweinebacke now it works out of the box. Still I’ve got not clue what your code does... would be super super cool if you could explain it

Comment: @Kalaschnik `\newmarks` and `\firstmarks` are e-TeX extensions to TeX's original `\mark`/`\firstmark`. They allow to use additional mark registers (originally TeX had only one). The rest of the code (the part I've added to esdd's original code) is an adaption of LaTeX's `\markboth` definition for that new mark.